# How do I find the gap between two objects on a moving conveyor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am needing to find the gap between two pieces of wood on a conveyor belt. I am new to this and am having trouble knowing what to Google to find the right formulas. I found one answer that helped a little, but it was dealing with two conveyors, and I am not sure if I adjusted the formula correctly. I will include what I did as a reference and hopefully someone can let me know if I did this right.

L (product length) = 37 inches

Vx (Upstream Speed) = 145 FPM

G (gap) = ?

Time = 37/145 = .25517

Distance = 145 * .25517 = 45.93101

Gap = 45.93101 - 37 = 8.9 inches

Comment: the formulas are nonsense until you know exactly how the gap is measured and how fast the conveyor moves

Comment: Please format the formulae into separate lines. In the current from, it is difficult to read.

Comment: Check on here - similar questions have been asked before.

Comment: It is not clear what you can measure... Can you measure the time between two woods? The formulas $Distance = 145 * .25517 = 45.93101$ is not correct. the result should be 37 not 45.9310.

Comment: What does FPM mean? Assuming that FPM means Feet Per Minute, we are missing the important metric of pieces of wood per minute. If we had that, it would be easy to calculate the gap.

Comment: @Chris_abc Yes, sorry FPM is Feet Per Minute. The conveyor is moving at 145 Feet Per Minute. To get pieces per minute, I can take the FPM of 145 and divide by the length in feet, 3.083333. I get 47.027 PPM. How can I move forward to calculate the gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by what you stated in your comments, your formula would be

$ \frac{speed}{(length+gap)} = f $

Where $f$ is your frequency, or pieces per minute.

If you assume (as you did in your comment) that $speed/length = f$, you are assuming a gap between each piece of wood of 0.

P.s. there is a mistake in the calculations, as NMech is noted. you are now saying:

$\frac{37}{145}*145 = 45.9 \\ 37*\frac{145}{145} = 45.9\\ 37* \frac{1}{1} = 45.9\\ 37 = 45.9$

p.p.s. In the formula above, be careful to fill in the numbers with corresponding units.

Answer (score 0):

Time them.  Distance = speed times time.

Or meaure them with a camera.

Conveyors create gaps via speedup belts.